# Django: setting initial in get_context_data doesn't work as expected

Tags: django

I am trying to set initial within a class based view, to pre-populate a text input with name=description

The following code seems to accept an integer input in the url as specified, and puts this where I want it in the template.

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns += (
    path('repair/', views.RepairListView.as_view(), name='app_name_repair_list'),
    path('repair/create/<int:pk>', views.RepairCreateView.as_view(), name='app_name_repair_create'),
)

# views.py
class RepairCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Repair
    form_class = RepairForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RepairCreateView , self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.initial['description'] = self.kwargs['pk']
return context
```

However when accessing in the browser...

access: /repair/create/1
text input contains: 1

access: /repair/create/2
text input contains: 1 (again)

access: /repair/create/3
text input contains: 2

(and so forth)

Have I done something blatantly wrong here or is this some kind of weird bug? I'm basically plan to have a URL somewhere else on the site, that the user would click to load this form, thus populating the form with already known information which would be in said URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initial` is a class attribute, shared by all instances. You shouldn't modify it.

Instead, you should define the `get_initial` method, returning a new dictionary:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {'description': self.kwargs['pk']}
```